# Replace value in array with numpy.random.normal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
myArray1 = np.array([[255, 255, 255,   1,   1, 255, 255, 255],
                     [255,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 255, 255]])
```

I want to create a new array `myArray2` based on `myArray1`. Where `myArray1`  has a value of 1, I want to replace the value by `numpy.random.normal(loc=40, scale=10)`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Ok. And "I can I do that?" should probably rather be "**How** can I do that?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is called `a`, you can do

```
b = a == 1
a[b] = numpy.random.normal(loc=40, scale=10, size=b.sum())
```

This avoids Python loops and takes advantage of Numpy's performance.

The first line creates a Boolean array with the same shape as `a` that is `True` in all entries that correspond to ones in `a`.  The second line uses [advanced indexing with this Boolean array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean) to assign new values only to the places where `b` is `True`.

Comment: That is interesting. But I get `ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape`

Comment: @ustroetz: Sorry, I copied the wrong version.  Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
[i if i != 1 else numpy.random.normal(loc=40, scale=10) for j in myArray1 for i in j]
```

`j` loops through each of the rows of `myArray1` and `i` loops through each element of the row.