# Mask array based on other array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have a numpy array `arrayBig`

```
10  5 27 30 34
2  34 23  2  3 
2  3  43 12 23
2  24 34  2 34
```

And I have a numpy array `arraySmall`

```
1 0 0 
0 1 1
1 1 0
```

What I want is a numpy array `arrayNew`

```
34 0 0 
0 43 12
24 34 0
```

I know my `arraySmall` has the shape `(3,3)` and is located at index `(1 1)` in  `arrayBig`. How can I get `arrayNew` with Numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrayBig = np.array([
...     [10,  5, 27, 30, 34],
...     [2,  34, 23,  2,  3],
...     [2,   3, 43, 12, 23],
...     [2,  24, 34,  2, 34],
... ])
>>> arraySmall = np.array([
...     [1, 0, 0],
...     [0, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 0],
... ])
>>> arrayBig[1:4, 1:4] * arraySmall
array([[34,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 43, 12],
       [24, 34,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I [recently learned about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556813/2088135) [advanced boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean). I'm not sure if it's any better than the other answer but you can do:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
>>> c = b == 0
>>> d = a[0:b.shape[0],0:b.shape[1]]
>>> d[c] = 0
>>> d
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 5]])
```